# Program Internet Explorer and ActiveX

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, pdf, internet-explorer, activex

I have a problem on a client computer running Windows 10 v20H2 with Internet Explorer and an ActiveX control; when trying to open a PDF in Internet Explorer, the program displays error:

```
Internet Explorer has restricted this webpage from running scripts and AcitveX controls
```

- This is not only an IE issue and all I can do is allow the blocked content, having to do so every time a new PDF is opened. On some PCs, we find that disabling/enabling AcrobatReader in IE Extensions fixes it, but not on all PCs; our question is about the IE issue, as IE is strongly
  connected in Windows Shell Explorer and we relate this to IE's configuration
- We have issues with code:

  ```vb
  $_static_oShellExplorer = ObjCreate("Shell.Explorer.2")
  $_static_idAcrobatReader_GUI_CTRL_AX = GUICtrlCreateObj($_static_oShellExplorer, 0, 0, $iWidth - 16, $iHeight - 39)

  $_static_oShellExplorer.navigate($sFile)
  ```

Has anyone ever encountered such a situation and can help?

Comment: IE has been pretty much phased out by Microsoft. See if you can set Active-X in IE Settings:   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-activex-controls-for-internet-explorer-11-25738d05-d357-39b4-eb2f-fdd074bbf347

Comment: IE should not be used and is no longer supported by Microsoft, nor is it secure - its last update was in ~2017ish and it should be removed from any machine it's installed on due to a vulnerability in a specific file format specific to IE that is exploitable in Windows with no security patch available _(the only way to ensure the exploit cannot occur is by removing IE)_. If a site requires IE, use [IE Tab](http://www.blackfishsoftware.com/) in a chromium-based browser, such as [Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge).

Comment: ActiveX is end of life, same as IE 11. Both went unsupported last August. Now would be time to remove dependencies on either of these technologies.

Comment: So what about customers who use IE all the time and work without any problems ?

Comment: IE is end of life. No more support, no more security updates. Don't use it. use Edge with IE11 support, which will allow ActiveX for a while. But now is the time to transition away from those technologies… **before** they're locked out later this year.

Comment: This is not only related to IE , we only observes this is related to IE, but we truly have problem with `ObjCreate("Shell.Explorer.2")`, we want to know how to solve the problem in IE as this is strongly related to Windows Shell Explorer, on some computers we was able to fix it with Enabling AcrobatReader in IE Extensions, but on few others computers we still have the same problem.

Comment: @PiotrT Some businesses have Microsoft LTSB contracts, however there is no secure way in which to use IE, nor is there a need to as all Chromium-based browsers can emulate IE for legacy sites requiring IE via IE Tab. IE should be completely removed from all machines it's installed upon due to an exploitable vulnerability in an IE-specific web file for which there is no patch for. Microsoft has been recommending to everyone, businesses included, to stop using IE since ~2017.

Comment: The final death knell will probably be this August, when Office will drop all support for it. That will hopefully finally force people over.

Comment: I just edit OP question as I and @PiotrT work together, and I know more about this issue, please follow my comments and wait for edit approval

Comment: @MichałLipok Is there a reason why you won't simply use a Chromium-based browser with IE Tab? Please refer to my previous comments

Comment: As I said we are using "ObjCreate("Shell.Explorer.2")" to embed AcrobatReader in our own GUI this is our main goal. The isue with `Shell.Explorer.2` object is related to IE issue as we are discover that some cases we are able to fix the issue by disabling/enabling AcorbatReader extension in IE.
In other cases after disabling/enagling this extension in IE the isue still occurs.

Comment: "Has anyone ever encountered such a situation and can help?" - Yes; Internet Explorer is configured to block the content by default.  Are you an Administrator on this machine?  It's typically blocked by a group policy, and unlike everyone who is talking about IE11 being out of support, I am looking to answer your question.  Is [`Automatic prompting for ActiveX controls` enabled or disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038724/how-to-automatically-allow-blocked-content-in-ie) Any edits or screenshots should provide an English translation otherwise I cannot help.

Comment: For IE, have you allowed "Allow active content to run in files on My Computer" in menu *Tools > Internet Options > Advanced tab* under Security? (If you can.)